# How to get items by sku using sell API?

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I'm working on ebay. I have created the application using sell api . I have fetched the Orders List using Postman. But when I try to fetch the items using SKU its giving me 500 [Internal Server error] . Although my request is complete and perfect.
why i am getting this error ? Is there any other API to get active inventory ? or get inventory by sku.
any link or suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have the same problem while working on the ebay sell API[REST]. It turns out that we cant get inventory item by sku.

we can only fetch the inventory items that is created using inventory item API. [here](https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/17883/cannot-get-my-listed-product-by-get-inventory-api.html?childToView=37361#answer-37361) you can read more about it.

Try to use Trading API's.

Comment: So it means we cant do anything. We have almost 1000 products. we have to create those products using inventory API's and then we will be able to fetch those ?

Comment: @Aisha  yes. you have to create those items via inventory item API.

Comment: You also can use Trading API which are SOAP based.

Comment: You need to migrate old listings to new listing using bulkmigrate endpoint of inventory api and then you can use inventory api.